# Array to Virtual Object

Tags: ruby, casting, jruby, data-transfer-objects

## Problem!

I was wondering if it is possible for an array to be transfered into a virtual object via method. Let's say that I have a class "Person" with two properties "@name" and "@lastname" and then I have an array containing this information, so What I need is to pass each array item into a new object from Person's class.

## Example #

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :lastname
  def initialize(name = "", lastname = "")
    @name = name
    @lastname = lastname
  end
end

array_of_names = [["lucia", "germes"], ["eder", "quiñones"], ["pedro", "infante"]]
array_of_names.each_with_index do |item, index|
  virtual_object = item.to_vo(Person.new)
  virtual_object.inspect
  # => "#<Person:0x0000FF @name="eder" @lastname="quiñones">
end
```

## Question?

Is this even possible by extending Array's class?

```
class Array
  def to_vo(object)
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
  end
end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

~ Eder Quiñones

Comment: What's a virtual object? Is it a JRuby term?

Comment: A quick search did not find a definition for me, either, but I wondered if the intention was something more like *generic,* where the method in `Array` could create any type of object. So, I answered the question that way and also with the idea of just creating `Person,` in case I misunderstood.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, no it's a design pattern mostly used to transfer data between applications. It's also known as DTO (Data Transfer Object)

Comment: @DigitalRoss, It was something more generic but I see that you had not trouble doing both! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

```
class Array
  def to_vo klass
    klass.new *self
  end
  # ..OR..
  def to_person
    Person.new *self
  end
end

p a.map { |e| e.to_vo Person }
p a.map(&:to_person)
```

Comment: What if the Class has no constructor (initializer)?

Comment: It will still work, because I used the *splat* only on the actual parameter, so it will expand to zero arguments.